# JavaScript: How to combine 2 arrays and keep the same index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays that i'd like to combine with eachother.

One array with numbers and another array with the title of those corresponding numbers. This data was returned from a csv file which is why I have the structure that I currently have.

Array 1: `dataResults = [  0: "494,927", 1: "48,883", 2: "59,976", 3: "1,205,915"  ]`

Array 2: `dataTitles = [ 0: "News", 1, "Retail", 2: "Real Estate" 3. "Accounting" ]`

I would like to combine these two arrays similar to an array of objects where index 0 is both `429,927` and has the title `news`.

Currently, I am getting these arrays by declaring a variable and pushing my data from the csv files into this array.

```
const dataResults = []

const dataTitles = []

dataResults.push =(dataList[1][5], dataList[2][5], dataList[3][5], dataList[4][5])
 //console logs = 0: "494,927", 1: "48,883", 2: "59,976", 3: "1,205,915"

dataResults.push = (dataList[0][1], dataList[0][2], dataList[0][3], dataList[0][4])
// console.log = 0: "News", 1, "Retail", 2: "Real Estate" 3. "Accounting"
```

What I've tried doing is just including both pushes into one but what that does is create additional index of array for example.`0: "News", 1: "494,927"` which I would want them to return both as index 0

My expected outcome something similar to a json object I believe `0 : [{ title: "News", result: "494,927 }]"` Where I can access both results as index zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` like this:

```js
const data = dataTitles.map((title, index) => ({
    title,
    result: dataResults[index]
}));
```